# android hide keyboard after pressing button

Tags: android, keyboard

anyone know if android is possible to hide the keyboard of a inputText after pressing a button?

in my application the keyboard is always present after a consultation which is uncomfortable for the user

Answer (score 10):

yes:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
});
```